# Command substitution and spaces

Tags: bash, command-substitution

Why does this work as a calculator:

```
[root@qabun02 ~]# echo $(( 5+2  ))
7
```

but this doesn't?

```
[root@qabun02 ~]# echo $( (5+2) )
-bash: 5+2: command not found
```

The only difference I can see is the absence of space between the brackets?

Also:

`[root@qabun02 ~]# echo $(who)
root pts/0 2015-01-28 09:53 (10.40.0.115)
[root@qabun02 ~]# echo $((who))
0`

How does command substitution respond to `((` and `( (` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$(` starts command substitution whereas `$((` starts arithmetic expansion.

`$( (5+2) )` is the command `(5+2)` i.e. the command `5+2` in a subshell. But that isn't a valid command.

`$((who))` is replaced by the value of the variable `who` which is probably undefined i.e. 0.

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

`$(...)` means sub-command substitution (similar to `...`);

`$((...))` means arithmetic evaluation substitution;

`${...}` means variable/parameter substitution;

The `$((` should be seen as an atomic sequence of characters (necessarily terminated by a `))`), it is by no mean equivalent to `$ ((`, `$( (` or `$ ( (`.

OBS: without the `$` immediately preceding it, a `(` is just a `(` and can be used within a `$((...))` block to determine precedence of arithmetic evaluation (like `$(( (3+4)*5 ))` differs from `$(( 3+4*5 ))`.

Comment: `$((` is not necessarily atomic. Behaviour for `$((foo)|(bar))` varies with shells.

Comment: I begin the answer with "in bash:"... :)

Comment: Well, in `bash`, `$((foo)|(bar))` does process substitution.